# PHP url if statement won't work ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])

Tags: php, session

I'm new to the forum. I have a problem in if statement when equalizing `$host` with my url. I tried echo `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, both works fine. Also removing `$_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true &&` didn't help either. I found the problem is in `if` statement I just can't solve it. Would appreciate any tips. Thanks in advance. Here's the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){

  echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";

} else if($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true && $host == 'myURL'){

  echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";

} else if($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true && $host == 'myURL'){

  echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";

} else{
  echo "<li><a href='#sec1'>Link_text</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a href='#sec2'>Link_text</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a href='#sec3'>Link_text</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a href='#sec4'>Link_text</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
}
?>
```

New fixed working code. Thanks everyone.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){

    if($host == 'myURL/'){
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
    }else if($host == 'myURL'){
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
    }else if($host == 'myURL'){
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
    }else{
        echo "<li><a href='#sec1'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#sec2'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#sec3'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#sec4'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
    }

}else{

    if($host == 'myURL/'){
        echo "<li><a href='#sec1'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#sec2'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#sec3'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#sec4'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
    }else{
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you might have done wrong, since you've replaced the actual value that you're comparing to with a dummy `myURL`. Show the actual code.

Comment: Why do you need to test the URL anyway? If this script is running, doesn't it have to be your URL?

Comment: You have two `else if` blocks that have the same test. Only the first one will ever run.

Comment: Yeah but myURL is not variable, in both else if statements URL is different.

Comment: You'll never get to the `else if` blocks because the `if` block will be executed when the user is logged in.

Comment: echo your `$host` and echo its url; your answer lies in there. Check that the session does in fact hold true. Only *you* know its true value and we don't know what that's coming from or used after.

Comment: Echo $host works fine and session is set to true when logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else if` tests are only performed if the `if` test fails. If the user is logged in, the `if` block will be executed, so it will never perform either of the `else if` tests. You need to nest the `$host` tests inside that block.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
    echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
    switch ($host) {
    case 'myURL1':
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
        break;
    case 'myURL2':
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='https://myURL' >Link_text</a></li>";
        break;
    }
} else {
    echo "<li><a href='#sec1'>Link_text</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='#sec2'>Link_text</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='#sec3'>Link_text</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='#sec4'>Link_text</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='https://myURL'>Link_text</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw the logic in your code and fixed my problem.